# how can i get the nodes that dont have children in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

i was wondering if there is a way to get all nodes that don't have any children in CakePHP. I found no mention of this in the documentation. (I am using CakePHP 2.x)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have a tree behavior

since tree behavior uses MPTT (see this [**link**](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/)) you can use `lft` and `rght` columns to perform your query since in leaf nodes `lft` and `rght` differs by one

```
$this->Model->find()
    ->where(['rght - lft =' => 1]);
```